# Elasticsearch - return aggregation to match a specific value?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

Using Elasticsearch 2, is it possible to return an aggregation where a document category matches a specific field value? For example, I want to get all the categories where categories.type = "application".

My mapping looks like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "products": {
        "_all": {
            "enabled": true
        }, 
        "properties": { 
            "title": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "categories": {
                "type":"nested",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string", 
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My query looks like this, which returns all category types, but I want to filter just the ones where categories.type = "application".

```
{  
    "query":{  
        "multi_match": {  
            "query": "Sound",
            "fields": [  
                "title"
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "Applications": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "categories"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "meta": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "categories.type"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "name": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "categories.name"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [aggregation filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_filter_bucket.html) if I understand correctly:

```
{   
    size : 50,
    "query":{  
        "multi_match": {  
            "query": "Sound",
            "fields": [  
                "title"
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "Applications": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "categories"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "meta": {
                    "filter" : {
                        "term" : {
                            "categories.type" : "application"
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "name": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "categories.name"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helpes.

Comment: Is there a way to add boolean logic to the aggregation, something like categories.type = "application" or "sensors"?

Comment: Yes. You can use bool filter. Change filter part as: "filter":{"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"categories.type":"application"}},{"term":{"categories.type":"sensor"}}]}}

Comment: do you know how I can specify a size parameter to this aggregation? It defaults to 10, but I want to get 50 of them.

Comment: Just add size: 50, at the top

Comment: I'm getting an error when I add "size": 3 (or whatever) when I try to add it anywhere in the aggregation. Where exactly should it go?

Comment: Updated answer. Can you try?

Comment: Yea, but that gives me 50 hits. I want to change the number of "Application" aggregations returned in the bucket.

Comment: Ahhh... I put "size": 50 in the "terms" object under the "field" property.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace "include": ".*" to "include": "application"

```
{  
    "query":{  
        "multi_match": {  
            "query": "Sound",
            "fields": [  
                "title"
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "Applications": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "categories"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "meta": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "categories.type"
                        , "include": "application"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "name": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "categories.name"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to only match documents that have an application category type. I want to aggregate categories that match a specific category type from the matched documents.

Comment: I see. I have changed the answer. You just need to replace **"include": ".*"** with **"include": "application"**